# GraphQL. Привязка сущностей друг к другу

Tags: graphql

Допустим у нас есть 2 связанные сущности, пусть это будет некая `group`:

```
group: {
  id,
  name
}
```

и некая `user`:

```
user: {
  id,
  name,
  age,
  groups
}
```

В старом добром rest, еслиб я захотел некого Васю добавить в группу Админов и еще какую-нибудь, я бы послал какой-то такой запрос:

```
PUT /user/1

{"id":1,"name":"Вася","age":30,"groups":[1,2]}
```

Либо добавил бы специальный endpoint для привязки пользователя к группам. Что-то вроде:

```
POST /user/1/groups

[1,2]
```

**Вопрос:**
Как выглядит такое-же действие в терминах `GraphQL`?

Comment: если знаете ответ, подскажите пожалуйста на мой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186709/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-graphql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Запрос будет очень похож на рестовый:

```
mutation {
  updateUser (
    id: 1,
    name: "Вася",
    age: 30,
    groups: [1,2]
  ) {
    id,name,age.groups
  }
}
```